# Returning html from lambda function using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda that I created that runs an express app. The express app has one route that supports a `get` request and returns a simple HTML page. I'm running this with `awsServerlessExpress`, but instead of just HTML being returned, JSON is being returned.

Here is what is being returned:

```
{"statusCode":200,"body":"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
Testing!
\r\n
\r\n
This is a test

\r\n
\r\n\r\n\r\n","headers":{"x-powered-by":"Express","accept-ranges":"bytes","cache-control":"public, max-age=0","last-modified":"Sun, 28 Oct 2018 23:48:18 GMT","etag":"W/\"b3-166bd1405d0\"","content-type":"text/html; charset=UTF-8","content-length":"179","date":"Mon, 29 Oct 2018 03:57:27 GMT","connection":"close"},"isBase64Encoded":false}
```

How can I get it to just return the HTML?

Here is my `app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"));


app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

app.use('/', router);

module.exports = app;
```

Here is my `index.js`

```
'use strict'

const binaryMimeTypes = [
  'application/javascript',
  'application/json',
  'application/octet-stream',
  'application/xml',
  'font/eot',
  'font/opentype',
  'font/otf',
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/png',
  'image/svg+xml',
  'text/comma-separated-values',
  'text/css',
  'text/html',
  'text/javascript',
  'text/plain',
  'text/text',
  'text/xml',
  'multipart/form-data'
]

const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express')
const app = require('./app')
const server = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(app)

exports.handler = (event, context) => { awsServerlessExpress.proxy(server, event, context) }
```

In AWS, I created a new Lambda with API Gateway as the trigger. Here is what my API Gateway looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable lambda proxy integration in API Gateway.
Check `Use Lambda Proxy integration` box in `Integration Request` settings.

[aws-serverless-express](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express) uses lambda proxy for mapping request and response.